# Pandas: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str' with more complex selection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to build a new dataframe based on selection criteria from the first dataframe.

```
df_selected = df_in.loc[ (df_in['featureclass'] == 'P' | df_in['featureclass'] == 'A') &
                         (df_in['admin1code'] == 'TX')
                   ]
```

returns this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Answer (score 1):

Need to wrap each boolean in it's own set of parentheses.

```
df_selected = df_in.loc[ ((df_in['featureclass'] == 'P') | (df_in['featureclass'] == 'A')) &
                         (df_in['admin1code'] == 'TX')
                       ]
```

Comment: It's not Pandas specific. It concern [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in Python. because `==` is evaluated after `|`.